# FBX export missing cloth modified mesh

Tags: cloth-simulation, .fbx, unreal-engine

Ok I spent hours trying to figure out the cloth modifier trying to get the cape in the pic to work properly. I FINALLY GOT IT lol. Now im having the issue of the exporting it. In blender it works and shows up perfectly fine.

[image]

Idk if its a setting in blender or not but i export to an FBX and import it in UE4. the cape wont show up.

[image]

im breaking my head over this so if anyone knows something i dont it will be greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I dont think its the materials. before i applied the cloth modifier the cape used the same materials and it showed up but in ue4 it was more like a car hood so i applied the modifier to make it more realistic and now that i have i export the model and the cape is a no show in ue4.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is you dont use blender for unreal cloth. I think you make the cape in blender same as any other mesh, then import it into unreal and do the cloth there. Unreal used to use something called apex cloth (which it still can), but now also has its own cloth authoring tools.

Here is a link to a video showing unreals clothing system, if you skip to 5:00 exactly it will show you how to author cloth with the new system in ue4.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZN3WHh3M9M

Comment: Absolutely. I just figured that out last night made a big difference and so much easier. Thanks a lot MajorTom